# How to connect esp32 to cloud mqtt broker without wifi using SIM800 with nodemcu Lua?

Tags: lua, esp32, nodemcu, sim800

I want to implement smart motor controller with esp32(nodemcu firmware https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32 with lua 5.1) my project is mqtt and wifi based so for that I needed a wifi router. But instead of using router/dongle at my farm I decided to use SI800C. I searched internet, how to pubish/subscribe mqtt with ESP32 without wifi and with internet from SIM800C and I got any refernces some of them are https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cloud-mqtt-broker-sim800l/,https://microdigisoft.com/esp32-ttgo-t-call-sim800l-with-mqtt-broker-without-wifi/
I wanted to implement same with my ESP32(WROOM-32 DEVKIT V1) with Lua(nodemcu), above refernces are in Arduino so tried to understand, but don't have much knowledge of C++(as TinyGsm library which is crucial written in C++).
Please help me to complemte my project with SIM800C...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you find a Lua library that supports the SIM800. That would allow you to work with the NodeMCU ESP32 stock firmware. How about a SIM800 module that you can control via UART?

Comment: Hi @MarcelStör thanks for the response, I tried for library there're many library refences for arduino based like TinyGSM but for Lua I didn't find any  and I tried to understand TinyGSM library but it's taking time I'm not a C++ guy  so am still struggling. Yes I'm controlling GSM through UART only.